# MySQL: composite index fulltext+btree?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, indexing, full-text-search

I want a query that does a fulltext search on one field and then a sort on a different field (imagine searching some text document and order by publication date). The table has about 17M rows and they are more or less uniformly distributed in dates. This is to be used in a webapp request/response cycle, so the query has to finish in at most 200ms.

Schematically:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST('query') ORDER BY date=my_date DESC LIMIT 10;
```

One possibility is having a fulltext index on the text field and a btree on the publication date:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT index_name(text);
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table (date);
```

This doesn't work very well in my case. What happens is that MySQL evaluates two execution paths. One is using the fulltext index to find the relevant rows, and once they are selected use a FILESORT to sort those rows. The second is using the BTREE index to sort the entire table and then look for matches using a FULL TABLE SCAN. They're both bad. In my case MySQL chooses the former. The problem is that the first step can select some 30k results which it then has to sort, which means the entire query might take of the order 10 seconds.

So I was thinking: do composite indexes of FULLTEXT+BTREE exist? If you know how a FULLTEXT index works, it first tokenizes the column you're indexing and then builds an index for the tokens. It seems reasonable to me to imagine a composite index such that the second index is a BTREE in dates for each token. Does this exist in MySQL and if so what's the syntax?

BONUS QUESTION: If it doesn't exist in MySQL, would PostgreSQL perform better in this situation?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support such a composite index. It will depend on your query and data if you can overcome this - if you only have one (or maybe 2-3) search terms (or if your source text is mainly 1 word, although I doubt that), you could build your own lookup table. You should test if the ordering is actually the problem (remove the order and the limit), as sorting 30k rows does not take that much time. PostgreSQL actually supports something like such an index (although it's not perfect for such a search) and will probably be a bit faster, but not down to 200ms (but these are just guesses!)

Comment: @solarflare I've tried removing the ORDER BY and the LIMIT. I've tried two queries. One with 300+ results which took 19 seconds and other with 2000+ results which took 59 seconds. However, if you add LIMIT (but not ORDER BY) now the queries take around 300-500ms. This suggests tome that indeed the issue is not the ordering bit, butt he collecting all maches bit (I took care to disable caching when running these experiments). Does this information help you understand what's going on?

Comment: @Solarflare Second point is: if MySQL doesn't support this composite index, how do people do it? You see all the time searches which you can sort. It's not unusual at all. How are they doing it?

Comment: Unfortunately, a fulltext index is special, and collecting larger resultsets takes time (although 60 seconds seems much, some of that time might be spend sending the result - play around with e.g. `select count(my_date) from ...`). "How are they doing it" is such a general question, there's no answer. You have to check every "it" for that. Maybe the searches you think of are no fulltext searches (or are on a small table), maybe they do not use MySQL, maybe they cache or precalculate searches (e.g. for the most common search terms), maybe they found some trick for their specific data, ...

Comment: @Solarflare Any clue if postgresql is any better here?

Comment: @Solarflare BTW you're correct, doing `count(*)` takes of order 50ms. So again, it's not that the index is slow, it's the getting the data that takes time.

Comment: As mentioned in my first comment: PostgreSQL is probably at least a bit faster (and even has such a composite index) but probably won't get down to 200ms. But that is just a guess and the only way to know for sure is if you test it. For the `count(*)`-test: do not use `*`, but a different column (preferable one that can be `null`), simulating the lookup mysql needs to do to get the other columns, just without actually ordering it. Maybe do a `select count(distinct my_date) ...` too. But it will not solve your problem (you may just test some limitations of fulltext indexes).

Comment: @Solarflare "simulating the lookup mysql needs to do to get the other columns" I'm confused now. I tried `count` on a column that can be NULL and indeed now it takes 20 secs (as opposed to 50ms with `count(*)`). To me this shows that the index itself is fast (after all, we can quickly find how many matches we have so the index must be working) but surprisingly the adidtional step of reading the data takes a long time. In this specific case there's only 1500 rows. I don't understand why accessing that (especially since it doesnt have to be printed) takes 20 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN BOOLEAN MODE`.

The date index is not useful.  There is no way to combine the two indexes.

Beware, if a user searches for something that shows up in 30K rows, the query will be slow.  There is no straightforward away around it.

I suspect you have a `TEXT` column in the table?  If so, there is hope.  Instead of blindly doing `SELECT *`, let's first find the ids and get the `LIMIT` applied, *then* do the `*`.

```
SELECT a.* 
    FROM tbl AS a
    JOIN ( SELECT date, id
             FROM tbl
             WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST (...)
             ORDER BY date DESC
             LIMIT 10 ) AS x
        USING(date, id)
    ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Together with

```
PRIMARY KEY(date, id),
INDEX(id),
FULLTEXT(...)
```

This formulation and indexing should work like this:

1. Use `FULLTEXT` to find 30K rows, deliver the PK.
2. With the PK, sort 30K rows by `date`.
3. Pick the last 10, delivering `date, id`
4. Reach back into the table 10 times using the PK.
5. Sort again.  (Yeah, this is necessary.)

**More** (Responding to a plethora of Comments):

The goal behind my reformulation is to avoid fetching *all* columns of *30K* rows.  Instead, it fetches only the `PRIMARY KEY`, then whittles that down to 10, then fetches `*` only 10 rows.  Much less stuff shoveled around.

Concerning `COUNT` on an InnoDB table:

- INDEX(col) makes it so that an *index* scan works for `SELECT COUNT(*)` or `SELECT COUNT(col)` without a `WHERE`.
- Without `INDEX(col),`SELECT COUNT(*)`will use the "smallest" index; but`SELECT COUNT(col)` will need a *table* scan.
- A table scan is *usually* slower than an index scan.
- Be careful of timing -- It is significantly affected by whether the index and/or table is already cached in RAM.

Another thing about `FULLTEXT` is the `+` in front of words -- to say that each word must exist, else there is no match.  This may cut down on the 30K.

The `FULLTEXT` index will deliver the `date, id` is random order, not PK order.  Anyway, it is 'wrong' to assume any ordering, hence it is 'right' to add `ORDER BY`, then let the Optimizer toss it if it *knows* that it is redundant.  And sometimes the Optimizer can take advantage of the `ORDER BY` (not in your case).

Removing just the `ORDER BY`, in many cases, makes a query run much faster.  This is because it avoids fetching, say, 30K rows and sorting them.  Instead it simply delivers "any" 10 rows.

(I have not experience with Postgres, so I cannot address that question.)

Comment: "Beware, if a user searches for something that shows up in 30K rows, the query will be slow. There is no straightforward away around it." But his was precisely the point of my question. You say that there's no way around it, but by combining the two indexes it should be doabe. Plenty of searches out there manage to search and sort so a solution must exist, right?

Comment: I love your idea of making (data,id) a primary key, but then you still that "if a user searches for something that shows up in 30K rows....". Giving that you're using LIMIT 10 I would have expected that your primary key solves this problem, no? Even if the match has 30k rows, the fact that you have a LIMIT in the inner query together with that primary key should solve this, no? (I'm asking before ahead of re-building my 17M row table to test your solution :-P)

Comment: Also, have you read my discussion with @SolarFlare on the comments? He said (and I tested and it's true) that by doing `SELECT COUNT(col) FROM tbl MATCH etc` where `col` is a nullable column, the query is super slow even though it doesn't involve actually fetching that many rows, which to me says that maybe there's something wrong with the index itself....?

Comment: And lastly, what is the significance of `IN BOOLEAN MODE` in your solution? It seems to me that the idea of your solution should work regardless. I ask this because another thing that I have in the pipeline to work on is increase match relevance (in some very basic ways, nothing very sophisticated)

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't improve it. The problem doesn't seem to be actually getting the data, but finding where it is. I tried doing your inner query: `select date,id from tbl where match(...) against (query) order by date desc limit 10;` Worst case I've seen is this taking 2 minutes. This is surprising to me because making the primary key `(date,id)` the rows should already be sorted by `date`. I got the impression I'm missing something.

Comment: By removing `order by` but leaving `limit 10` i just noticed that some times the results don't come in the order of the primary key. Shouldn't it? I thought that results would come in the order of the primary key unless you use `order by` on it.... If that's not true, then I wouldn't expect your solution to work but you're still going to do a thousand rows `order by` potentially.

Comment: I just checked that's not true: without `order by` you don't get the primary key ordering. So I guess that's the reason your solution doesn't work :-/

Comment: @solarflare said that postgresql has a fulltext+btree composite index. Should I just try that?