# postgres: Composite fulltext / btree index

Tags: postgresql, sorting, full-text-search

I want to do a fulltext search on one column and sort in a different column. If I index these two columns separately postgres can't use both indexes in this query. Is there a way to create a composite index that could be used in this scenario?

Comment: Which type of column you're sorting on ? And what type of sorting do you need ?

Comment: @PaoloMelchiorre Sorting on a date. I'm actually using MySQL, not postgres, but I was considering moving if postgres could solve this issue for me. I've described it in more detail here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296819/mysql-composite-index-fulltextbtree but that question it's really dependant on MySQL specifics.

Comment: In a similar scenario I build a GiST index on a tsvector column and on another tetxt colum with gist_trgm_ops operator so I actually did a full-text search with the tsvector column and then ordered on the other text column with trigram distance value using only one index.
But in your situation you have a date and I don't know if it can works.

Comment: Could you explain what this means "and then ordered on the other text column with trigram distance value using only one index."? Maybe it can be adapted.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.

While you can attach scalar columns to a GIN index via the [`btree_gin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gin.html) contrib module, Postgres can't use a GIN index for sorting. From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-ordering.html):

> Of the index types currently supported by PostgreSQL, only B-tree can
>   produce sorted output — the other index types return matching rows in
>   an unspecified, implementation-dependent order.

Comment: Alright, follow up question. How do websites do such quick search+sort? I've seen this everywhere (example: e-commerce search and sort by price).

Comment: @oneloop: Not my area of expertise, but StackOverflow does this, and it looks like they're using Elasticsearch: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10370

Comment: But then I'll ask, How does Elasticsearch do it? What is the actual structure of the index that does this, and can I have it in postgres/mysql?

Comment: @oneloop: Never used Elasticsearch, so I'm not sure how it works. AFAICT a composite GIN index actually *is* an appropriate structure for this kind of search - the index entry for each lexeme would contain a date-ordered B-tree of heap pointers - but Postgres doesn't (and under the current design, can't) know how to make use of this to optimise an `ORDER BY`. I'm not aware of anything in Postgres which would help; I guess that, in most use cases, the results of a full-text search are few enough that an in-memory sort isn't a significant overhead.

Comment: "I guess that, in most use cases, the results of a full-text search are few enough that an in-memory sort isn't a significant overhead" You precisely nailed it. That assumption is not true for my case, unfortunately, often having 30k results. In MySQL this is too slow (in the order of seconds). I'll have to try postgres when I have the opportunity.

Comment: Also I think the problem isn't actually the sort, but grabbing 30k rows, effectively accessing the BTREE 30k times.

Comment: @oneloop: Sorting 30k rows by date takes <5ms on my five-year-old desktop (albeit with a somewhat contrived example); I'd be surprised if this was your bottleneck. Probably worth trying for yourself.

Comment: (P.S. My description of the GIN internals was a little off, though I don't think it affects the conclusion. They're described in detail [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-implementation.html).)

Comment: Like I said, I don't think it's the sorting itself, but the grabbing the 30k rows that you need to do in order to sort.

Comment: @oneloop: Oh, so you're also paginating the results? I'd assumed you were fetching all 30k rows at the end regardless. Disk I/O is often the killer here; throwing enough RAM at the problem to keep everything in cache (and tuning [`shared_buffers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-BUFFERS) accordingly) can make a huge difference (though obviously not always a practical solution).

Answer (score 0):

*I report as answer my previous comment with example on it*

> In a similar scenario I build a GiST index on a tsvector column and on
>   another tetxt colum with gist_trgm_ops operator so I actually did a
>   full-text search with the tsvector column and then ordered on the
>   other text column with trigram distance value using only one index.

I created an index on "title" and "search":

```
CREATE INDEX docs_docume_search_title_gist
  ON public.docs_document
  USING gist
  (title COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gist_trgm_ops, search);
```

In this query the full-text search is on "search" and the ordering is on "title" with trigram:

```
SELECT "title", ("title" <-> 'json') AS "distance"
FROM "docs_document"
WHERE ("release_id" = 22 AND "search" @@ (plainto_tsquery('json')) = true)
ORDER BY "distance" ASC
LIMIT 10
```

This is the explain:

```
Limit  (cost=0.40..71.99 rows=10 width=29)
  Output: title, (((title)::text <-> 'json'::text))
  ->  Index Scan using docs_docume_search_title_gist on public.docs_document  (cost=0.40..258.13 rows=36 width=29)
        Output: title, ((title)::text <-> 'json'::text)
        Index Cond: (docs_document.search @@ plainto_tsquery('json'::text))
        Order By: ((docs_document.title)::text <-> 'json'::text)
        Filter: (docs_document.release_id = 22)
```